# Pine script convert series[float] to type: float

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

in the following code the `renko` function only takes float value. But my brick calculation gives a series[float]. Is there a way to convert series[float] to float?

```
//@version=4
study("Example 7", overlay=true)

highestHigh = highest(high, 288)
lowestLows = lowest(low, 288)

brickSize = avg(highestHigh, lowestLows) * 0.005
renko_t = renko(syminfo.tickerid, "Traditional", brickSize)
renko_low = security(renko_t, timeframe.period, low)
plot(renko_low)
```

Error:

```
Compilation error. Line 11: Cannot call 'renko' with 'param'=series[float]. The argument should be of type: float;
line 12: Undeclared identifier 'renko_t';
line 13: Undeclared identifier 'renko_low'
```

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript there is no way to convert a serie float to a float.
You will have to modify the way you make your calculations to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Oh, thanks! So is there a way to get 24hr high/low in float type?